# Make immuteable third party classes

Tags: java, loops, jakarta-ee

I have two classes let say Student and Book as followed.

Student.java

```
    public final class Student {

    private final String name;
    private final Book book;

    public Student(String name, Book book) {
        this.name = name;
        this.book = book;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the book
     */
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }
}
```

Book.java

```
    public final class Book {

    private int pages;

    /**
     * @return the pages
     */
    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    /**
     * @param pages
     *            the pages to set
     */
    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

Student class is my class but book class is third party class.
I want to use Book in my Student class and make the Student object as immutable ?
Can any one guide me how to do this ?

```
    public final class Immutable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b = new Book();
        b.setPages(35);
        Student s = new Student("kiran", b);
        System.out.println(s.getBook().getPages());
        s.getBook().setPages(56);
        System.out.println(s.getBook().getPages());

    }
}
```

I have to restrict to not change the Book

I have to make the Student object is un mutable. Once Student object is created with name and book then SStudent object should not be changed. I mean if some XYZ Student  is created with 75 pages of book then the xyz student shoud be immutable I mean we can not change the book pages of this student.

Comment: Wrap all accesses to book so that they don't modify the inner class.

Comment: Remove the getBook method.

Comment: `Book` is not `final` (neither is `Student`, you should change that). Extend `Book` to make an `ImmutableBook`, copy the `Book` passed in the constructor and override the methods.

Answer (score 4):

I see two general ways of doing I see:

- Give only copies of the book out, thus any change won't reflect on the real book, but this is a bad idea, if you ask me, since it would confuse the hell out of everyone using it without reading the documentation carefully (if you write any).
- Create your own book. You COULD extend the old book, but this would mean throwing exceptions on or ignoring calls to the setter methods - again, confusing. So I would create a wrapper object that contains the original book but only offers getters as public methods. Example:

Example:

```
public class MyBook {
    private Book book;

    public MyBook(...) { 
       book = new Book(...);
    }

    public String getTitle() { 
       return book.getTitle();
    }

 ...etc
}
```

It probably also depends on the use case, in other words, on the "why" you need to use that Book class instead of creating your own and converting somewhere else.

Comment: Make `MyBook extends Book` for API compatibility. Call it something more descriptive.

Comment: To make it truly immutable, it should also be final. Otherwise extenders may add mutable fields.

Comment: @Boris-the-spider No, I would not to that, because then you would need to throw an Exception (for example UnsupportedOperationException) or ignore calls to the setter methods. Both tend to confuse the hell out of everyone. If I see a setXYZ method, I assume it to set something and not to be totally ignored - or even worse, throw an error, because I'm not allowed to call the public method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Depends: If the reference to the original book itself isn't protected, but private, extending classes cannot access it and thus not add any mutable fields on it - only on the wrapper. We don't know if the whole thing should be immutable or just the original `Book`.

Comment: It seems that your intention is that the new book should be immutable. The OP merely asked for an immutable *`Student`*. So a copy would cover that fine. It seems to be your advice to make the book also immutable (to prevent confusion? Not sure why you'd think it's confusing). Thus, you should make it truly immutable, or *that* would confuse people just as badly.

Comment: Ok, this is probably unclear. I assumed that he wanted the whole student being immutable, including the book itself, which means that he cannot allow the book's values to be changed and neither the book itself to be changed in the Student.

Answer (score -2):

In `getBook()` of Student class perform cloning by `book.clone()`, provided that your `Book` class implements `Cloneable` interface and `clone()` method.